# Multiple column text file to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, key

I am attempting to do the following:

I have a file which can have any number of rows and columns (meaning number of rows/columns in the input file are not fixed). Also, note that there can be duplicate points (which is valid).
The format of the input file looks like the following:

```
Point Sample1_X_Coordinate Sample1_Y_Coordinate Sample2_X_Coordinate Sample2_Y_Coordinate and so on`

A     20                    10                  18                    9

B     16                    13                  15                    13

A     21                    11                  19                    9

C     8                     5                    8                    4
```

I need to store this file into something like the following for doing additional manipulations (adding pseudocode since I am very new to python):

`outputdata[this_sample][this_point].append((this_sample_point_X_coordinate, this_sample_point_Y_coordinate))`

i.e, the data to be stored in the following way:

```
outputdata[Sample1][A] = list[(20,10), (21,11)]

outputdata[Sample2][A] = list[(18,9), (19,9)]
```

How can I implement the above in python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done by opening the file, reading line-by-line and splitting the lines by spaces. The dictionary is tricky to initialize but with defaultdict objects it is fairly straightforward. For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Instantiate a dictionary which assumes dictionary of lists if the key does not exist
point_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
with open('textfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        # Split line using space as delimeter and remove new line character:
        point, x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.replace('\n', '').split(' ')
        point_dict['Sample1'][point].append((int(x1), int(y1)))
        point_dict['Sample2'][point].append((int(x2), int(y2)))
```

This results in:

```
point_dict['Sample1']
Out[13]: defaultdict(list, {'A': [(20, 10), (21, 11)], 'B': [(16, 13)], 'C': [(8, 5)]})

point_dict['Sample2']
Out[12]: defaultdict(list, {'A': [(18, 9), (19, 9)], 'B': [(15, 13)], 'C': [(8, 4)]})

point_dict['Sample1']['A']
Out[14]: [(20, 10), (21, 11)]
```